# stylecop does not underline errors in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop, underline

I got a new visual studio 2013, installed stylecop there. But it does not underline error how it used to be in VS 2012.

So, what's wrong?

EDIT. I have checked Resharper options-> plugins and stylecop is not listed there. May that be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that stylecop 4.7 is not compatible with resharper 8.0. Have to update to 8.1

Answer (score 1):

StyleCop does not perform underlining; ReSharper with the StyleCop plugin does.  Did you perhaps have ReSharper installed on VS 2012 but not on your new VS 2013?